# SWIFT Loading image progress show in Loader

Tags: uiimage, swift2, ios9, loader

I have an Imageview and I am  setting an Image via Alamofire + Haneke framework in viewDidLoad. I want to use SwiftLoader to show user progress until imageView have its image set. How to properly time this situation? I tried ViewDidAppear but its not accurate.

Comment: Can show your code and explain what do you mean by "not accurate"?

Comment: Image is not visible in ImageView and Loader will end loading. ...then image is set. I need something that can cover timing. I tried something with viewDidLoad and viewWillLoad but its not what I need.